# How to execute a test file that is not ending with spec.ts or test.ts with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, integration-testing

I am trying to differentiate unit tests from integration tests, and separating them into specific files.

More precisely, I'd like to use `inte.ts` file extension for integration tests.

I run unit tests maybe 30 times a day. I wish to run integration only when I choose too (maybe once a day).

But apparently I can't just execute :

```
➜  bff-candidates git:(develop) jest src/me/repository/me.repository.inte.ts
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /Users/amehmeto/HeroesJobs/BFF/bff-candidates/src
  137 files checked.
  testMatch:  - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 137 matches
  testRegex: .spec.ts$ - 32 matches
Pattern: src/me/repository/me.repository.inte.ts - 0 matches
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure the pattern you want in the testMatch or testRegex attribute on your jest config.

In this case, should be something like: `testMatch: ["**/inte.ts?(x)"]`

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-arraystring